# Using new io classes with numpy fromfile/tofile in Python 2 (converting io classes to file objects)

Tags: python, numpy, file-io

The functions `numpy.fromfile` and `ndarray.tofile` accept file objects in addition to file-names. Using a file object is important if the data is not at the beginning of the file or there is some other special requirement.

Internally, those functions use `FILE*` to do their work directly.

In Python 2, they use `PyFile_AsFile` to get the `FILE*`. This means that the file object must truly be a `file` object and not something that shares the interface with it (see [the source of `npy_PyFile_Dup2`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e05b75880911172ac2ca4a589aeca28c0ac38729/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h#L305)).

In Python 3, since `PyFile_AsFile` and the `file` object are gone they have to resort to accepting file-like objects and will work with anything that has `fileno`, `flush`, `tell`, and `seek` (see [the alternate source of `npy_PyFile_Dup2`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e05b75880911172ac2ca4a589aeca28c0ac38729/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h#L148)).

The question is then, how to get `fromfile`/`tofile` working Python 2 with `io` objects (given they actually support `fileno()`). Preferably in numpy v1.7+.

The ideas I have so far:

- Use `os.dup`, `os.fdopen`, and others to create a new `file` object from the `io` object. This however has some issues in that it needs to be closed specially (like in the numpy's Python 3 npy_PyFile_Dup2) to prevent issues with Python's internal buffering and I am don't completely understand all of the interactions between Python and the underlying `FILE*` handles. Additionally, it means a special function needs to be called to close this special object and data needs to be transferred (like original position) to the closing function.
- Make an alternate `fromfile`/`tofile` Using Cython to get the FILE* object from the `io` classes and calling the C functions [`PyArray_FromFile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_FromFile)/[`PyArray_ToFile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_ToFile) directly. This then requires Cython and assumes things about getting the `FILE*` from an `io` class.
- Same as above but using `ctypes`. A little more ugly but doesn't require Cython.

Of these methods, which is the 'best' way to do it? For the first one, how would one properly handle all the Python/underlying file IO issues? For the last two, how would one properly get the `FILE*` from a `io` class?